# Headless integration tests of an eclipse plugin with maven tycho

Tags: junit, eclipse-plugin, maven, headless, tycho

I wrote some Junit tests for my eclipse plugin. If I start my test suite as a **"JUnit Plug-in Test"** from Eclipse, everything is working fine.
Now I want to run them from Maven Tycho.

So I put the following packaging : **"eclipse-test-plugin"**, in the **pom.xml** and the integration tests start with a **"mvn clean integration-test"**. So I think my maven  configuration is quite OK.

But some tests are failing, and I suspect the headless build can't detect the [IMarkers](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/resources/IMarker.html) my tests are trying to detect, since IMarkers are UI components.

Am I right? Any idea to get my tests based on IMarkers running with Tycho?

Comment: It would be good if you could provide the error you are getting from the failed tests. I have found that looking the `[timestamp].log` file under `target/work/configuration` folder is often a good starting point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell test plugin that you want to run the test with a UI, by default it will run  with the headless runner.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
  <artifactId>tycho-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <useUIHarness>true</useUIHarness>
    <useUIThread>true</useUIThread>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```